# OpenVPN network-manager on proxies tab: PORT does not change from 120 [Ubuntu 18.04]

Tags: 18.04, proxy, openvpn

After installing openvpn with:

```
sudo apt install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

I tried adding an OpenVPN profile and had to add proxies in the Advanced tab
though the port is always at "120" and not updating after change.

Answer (score 1):

Set proxy port at "Misc" tab as "Connect timeout".It's not a Bug, it's a feature )))